# Hibernate, JDBC, Mysql, Cannot login into database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

When i connect with this code on my linux (Ubuntu 11.10) with mysql version 5.1 it works fine, but when i want to start my app on windows os (windows 7 with mysql 5.5) it throws exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

In both cases i was log in on localhost.
I tried to log in on root user. I have complete certainty it was correct password.
I tried to grand a all priviligates to new one user, but it was the same exception.
Another option i was try was that i catch a `GenericJDBCException` and program gives me this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I connect to database programmatically (via Hibernate AnnotationConfiguration):

```
annotationConfiguration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

// add annotatedClasses
annotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(X.class);

annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/" + database);
annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", userName);
annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
//annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.query.factory_class", "org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory");
if (StaticConstants.DEBUG) {
    annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
} else {
    annotationConfiguration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
}
annotationConfiguration.configure();
sessionFactory = annotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
sessionFactory.close();
```

I use Hibernate version 3.6.7, but i tested it on Hibernate 3.6.8 via Configuration class and it was the same result.

So my question is has someone the same problem and solve it, or anyone have any idea to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you connect to the database using commandline? i.e. mysql -u root -p

Comment: Can you try hardcoding localhost in the url.

Comment: no... but i should :) i check that but the same code works on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your credentials. your password for user root is wrong

Comment: the exception clearly says that a user root has tried to connect to the database with some password and MySQL didn't allow it

Comment: Check if you're authenticating against proper database. You may have several instances running in your environment

Comment: yes, you have right, but maybe there is some problem with hibernate or something like that - thats why i wrote here.

Comment: i have static variables with static methods to create connection, so it won't be a several instances

Comment: I mean several instances of MySQL running. This is not a code problem, but rather a configuration problem. Did you flush the privileges after you've granted them? Did you try to restart Mysql after granting the privileges?

Comment: i grand privileges by MySQL Workbench. I tried restart server several times. And there is one of instance of mysql server

Comment: try the following: 
connect from command prompt and issue commands manually:
create user testUser
grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'testUser'@* identified by 'testPassword' // note the star at the end of the database name
flush privileges // this is really important
Change your java code to reflect the new credentials.
Launch the app.

Comment: now it works. I am noooob, because i had bug in code (exactly my password was wrong). Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

First try login into mysql installed on win 7 from the command prompt.
Open command promt.Move to the bin folder of mysql installation.

C:\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p

Above line will prompt for password.Input password and see if you are able to login correctly